# Pass value from jQuery dropdown to simplecart.js

Tags: jquery, dropdownbox

I've lost at least two days of my life trying to pass some information from my dropdowns to the simplecart js cart so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to pass a value from a 'make' drop down and also from a 'model' drop down to simplecartjs but I'm not sure how to do this. My second drop down is populated based on the selection of the first drop down. How can I make an add to cart button that reads these values? Here is the dropdown code:

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#json-one").change(function() {

        var $dropdown = $(this);

        $.getJSON("compatibility.json", function(data) {

            var key = $dropdown.val();
            var vals = [];

            switch(key) {
                case 'Canon':
                    vals = data.Canon.split(",");
                    break;
                case 'Nikon':
                    vals = data.Nikon.split(",");
                    break;
                case 'base':
                    vals = ['Please choose from above'];
            }

            var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
            $jsontwo.empty();
            $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
                $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
            });

        });
    });

});
</script>
```

and here is the drop down html:

```
<select id="json-one">
    <option selected value="base">Camera Model</option>
    <option value="Canon">Canon</option>
    <option value="Nikon">Nikon</option>
</select>

<br />

<select id="json-two">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to read these selections and pass them to the add to cart button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work? (Pretty much taken from the simplecartjs.org docs)

Return as false if the requirements aren't met.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        /* current stuff */
    })();

    simpleCart.bind( 'beforeAdd' , function( item ){
        if( item.get( 'make' ) === '' || item.get( 'model' ) === ''){
            // If the dropdowns are empty or it you set them to none etc
            alert('Please remember to select a make and model');
            return false; // prevents item from being added to cart
        }
    });
</script>
```

And then make your drop down into a shelf item..

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <h2 class="item_name"> Awesome T-shirt </h2>
    <p>
        <select class="item_make" id="json-one">
            <option selected value="base">Camera Model</option>
            <option value="Canon">Canon</option>
            <option value="Nikon">Nikon</option>
        </select>

        <br />

        <select class="item_model" id="json-two">
            <option>Please choose from above</option>
        </select>

        <br />

        <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"><br>
        <span class="item_price">$xx.xx</span><br>
        <a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Add to Cart </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Qoop you hero! I'm almost there I've got the item make and model passing through the checkout to paypal. I just can't get the return as false to work. I presume this is because I'm a jquery amateur and havnt combined the two scripts properly. I'll keep trying and update later....

Comment: Qoop thank you so much! I just needed to insert the default drop down value into '' and now it works a charm! thanks!